# Heroku can't find existing table

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, heroku, web-deployment

So I just pushed my application to Heroku and it seemed to work for the first hour, people were able to sign up for my service, however after the first hour, whenever someone hit sign up they were taken to an error page. I then tried to relaunch the application, and again the same thing occurred, some people were initially able to sign up, but then again the app stopped working. The error message Heroku was giving me is below, but essentially it was saying it couldn't find the table. What makes this really confusing, is that it is able to find the table initially and then all of a sudden can't. I am new to Heroku and postgreSQL, and really don't know how to move forward now. The full error message is below.

```
2014-01-27T04:49:56.281018+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.message.DbException.ge
t(DbException.java:169) ~[com.h2database.h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
2014-01-27T04:49:56.280620+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.serve
r.query.CQuery.createPersistenceException(CQuery.java:790) ~[org.avaje.ebeanorm.
avaje-ebeanorm-3.2.2.jar:na]
2014-01-27T04:49:56.280620+00:00 app[web.1]: select t0.user_id c0, t0.first_name
 c1, t0.last_name c2, t0.full_name c3, t0.username c4, t0.gender c5, t0.fb_id c6
, t0.number_of_songs_requested c7 from echo_user t0
2014-01-27T04:49:56.280620+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.serve
r.core.OrmQueryRequest.findList(OrmQueryRequest.java:265) ~[org.avaje.ebeanorm.a
vaje-ebeanorm-3.2.2.jar:na]
2014-01-27T04:49:56.280446+00:00 app[web.1]: Bind values:[null]
2014-01-27T04:49:56.281018+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTab
leOrView(Parser.java:4824) ~[com.h2database.h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
2014-01-27T04:49:56.281018+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLExcep
tion: Table "ECHO_USER" not found; SQL statement:
2014-01-27T04:49:56.280278+00:00 app[web.1]: Query was:
2014-01-27T04:49:56.281018+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTab
leFilter(Parser.java:1099) ~[com.h2database.h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
2014-01-27T04:49:56.281018+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.message.DbException.ge
t(DbException.java:146) ~[com.h2database.h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
2014-01-27T04:49:56.281018+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.message.DbException.ge
tJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329) ~[com.h2database.h2-1.3.172.jar:1.3.172]
```

Here is a link to the application:

http://frozen-earth-1428.herokuapp.com/

I am using the play framework for writing the code. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have you checked whether the table is actually there? A convenient way to do so would be with an Heroku dataclip.

Comment: There is echo_user and  "ECHO_USER". What is the actual table name?